# Failing Docker install of Jupyter on Django

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook, divio

I'm following the recommended way to install jupyter on django by installing the following pip packages:

- jupyter
- ipython
- django-extensions

As described here for example:
https://medium.com/ayuth/how-to-use-django-in-jupyter-notebook-561ea2401852

it was working for a while but since some days is failing and I cannot figure out what the problem really is:

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-2xou1hp2/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index -- setuptools wheel 'ipython>=5' 'jupyter_core>=4.2' jupyter_client:
  ERROR: Collecting setuptools
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

something seems to have broken the install but I'm lost about what it is.

UPDATE:

I have uploaded a Docker based test project to Github to demostrate the issue:  ttps://github.com/vladox/test-divio-jupyter/blob/master/Dockerfile you will see the pip install command where the error occurs.

You may need to delete the pinned dependencies in requirements.txt to see the exact same error.

Comment: what command produces this error?

Comment: @RafalS I have a Docker test project and if you have a look on the Dockerfile here https://github.com/vladox/test-divio-jupyter/blob/master/Dockerfile you will see the pip install command where the error occurs. You may need to delete the pinned dependencies in requirements.txt to see the exact same error.